# Django import error - no module named django.conf.urls.defaults

Tags: python, django, graphite, django-1.6

I am trying to run statsd/graphite which uses django 1.6.

While accessing graphite URL, I get django module error

> File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/urls.py", line 15, in 
>        from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
>       ImportError: No module named defaults

However, I do not find **defaults** django package inside `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/`

Please help fixing this issue.

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.6

Answer (score 200, accepted):

`django.conf.urls.defaults` [has been removed in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-6). If the problem was in your own code, you would fix it by changing the import to

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
```

However, in your case the problem is in a third party app, graphite. The issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/commit/fc3f018544c19b90cc63797d18970a4cc27ef2ad#diff-e383725a971fca0685db19bfe7c65b32) in graphite's master branch and version 0.9.14+.

In Django 1.8+ you can remove `patterns` from the import, and use a list of `url()`s instead.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
```

Comment: Check also if you have set ROOT_URLCONF in your settings.py! This variable has to also be adapted. In my case it was ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls' and had to be changed to ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

Comment: patterns has been removed. You can directly use a python list to add urls instead of using patterns.

Comment: @Alasdair Was working with a code from django 1.6 and found the defaults replacement here. Just was adding to the answer. So that someone else could find all help at one place.

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you don't want to downgrade to Django 1.5.x or upgrade Graphite then you can apply [the fix](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/commit/fc3f018544c19b90cc63797d18970a4cc27ef2ad#diff-e383725a971fca0685db19bfe7c65b32) to your older Graphite with:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/from\ django\.conf\.urls\.defaults\ import\ \*/from\ django\.conf\.urls\ import\ \*/g' {} \;
```

..in your `<graphite_dir>/webapp/graphite` dir.

This helped me with my Graphite 0.9.12 and Django 1.7(.5).

(I also had to do:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/mimetype\=/content_type\=/g' {} \;
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/content_type\=mimetype/content_type\=content_type/g' {} \;
```

..later on as after I managed to start Graphite some of its features didn't work. Now they work for me but YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks, this still appears to be the case in the current iteration of this software! Your fixes work well for me in Graphite 0.9.12 and Django 1.6.1!

Answer (score 0):

go to the file location where you have installed python.
open cmd on that path and then install django with command >> pip install django

Then cross check on python shell with import django(which should do nothing)
or simply use the command >> python -m django --version

it will simply give you version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Eik.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAGiq.png)