# failed to install django-chronograph in django 1.7

Tags: django, django-chronograph

I tried to install `django-chronograph` to `django-1.7` for assigning scheduled task in my django web-app.

I followed the instruction as shown [here](https://django-chronograph.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) but it gives me the following error when running `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python manage.py syncdb`:

```
user@(none):~/mysite$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 23, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chronograph/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
ImportError: No module named defaults
```

Is it `django-chronograph` not supported by `django-1.7`?

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of this package, but if you search for that error you will find that [that import path hasn't worked since `Django 1.6`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19962822/2395796).

It could be that it's just the PyPI version that's old, and that the master branch works fine. However, [the last commit](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/commits/branch/default) to this package was in March 2013, and there's [an open issue](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/issue/33/fails-to-load-altogether-for-django-16) on the project's bitbucket page indicating that it fails to work on 1.6, so I doubt it.

In sum, it appears that this package supports neither Django 1.6 nor 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

[They already committed a fix](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/commits/4bfeebcdf5972f1dc662722f3637550481fbf516#Lchronograph/admin.pyT2), so to get rid of this error, don't go through:

```
pip install django-chronograph
```

I've just installed on Django 1.8 without issues (so far..) using:

```
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph@f561106f6aaab62f2817e08e51c799320fd916d9#egg=django-chronograph
```