# Install failed with Django-Chronograph by pip in django 1.10

Tags: python, django, pip, django-chronograph

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163591/failed-to-install-django-chronograph-in-django-1-7) question but i got a different error.

I'm try to installing via pip with:

```
pip install django-chronograph
```

I'm using python 2.7 and a virtualenv

```
pip freeze
Django==1.10
django-backbone==0.2.3
django-jstemplate==1.1.1
gunicorn==18.0
MySQL-python==1.2.5
six==1.10.0
South==0.7.6
unicodecsv==0.9.4
```

Error:

```
pip install django-chronograph
Collecting django-chronograph
  Using cached django-chronograph-0.3.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/87/h3ltndc5279cknk_vn9nzjjc0000gn/T/pip-build-_JDRxl/django-chronograph/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        setup_distribute()
      File "/private/var/folders/87/h3ltndc5279cknk_vn9nzjjc0000gn/T/pip-build-_JDRxl/django-chronograph/setup.py", line 18, in setup_distribute
        distribute_setup = __import__('distribute_setup')
      File "distribute_setup.py", line 1
        <html>
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/87/h3ltndc5279cknk_vn9nzjjc0000gn/T/pip-build-_JDRxl/django-chronograph/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the installation script provided by `django-chronograph`.

In line 16 of `setup.py`, it tries to download a script:
https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/src/f561106f6aaab62f2817e08e51c799320fd916d9/setup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#setup.py-16

in this code block:

```
try:
    import distribute_setup
except:
    # Make sure we have Distribute
    if not os.path.exists('distribute_setup'):
        urllib.urlretrieve('http://nightly.ziade.org/distribute_setup.py',
                           './distribute_setup.py')
```

However, when you visit the URL at `http://nightly.ziade.org/distribute_setup.py`, it gives a 404 error, thus the returned `html` in the error.

It looks like you might be able to get distribute here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.7.3

Or try doing this before you install django-chronograph:

```
pip install distribute
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

django-chronograph is unmaintained. Its fork is doing much better and has support for Django 2.0 and Django 2.1: https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker